# Distribution of genetic distances in a phylogenetic tree

Tags: distributions, phylogeny

I have a phylogentic tree of samples, and some samples belong to either of two groups. I'm trying to show that the mean pairwise distance of samples in one group is larger than the one from the other group.

I computed the pairwise genetic distance of all samples in a tree using cophenetic.phylo and obtaining the mean pairwise distance.

Does anyone know what the distribution of cophenetic.phylo distances is, so that i can test whether the difference between the mean pairwise distance of two groups, is greater than zero?